# Help with adapting a script to Multiple Outputs

Tags: command-line, text-processing

This script pulls out the matching "Group" Sports from my file to the output emby_sports.m3u. I have all the usual groups I.E. "News", "General Streams", "Movies".

**Is it possible to adapt this script to "Pull all the groups" in one run and separate them into multiple files, or
do I need a separate script for each one I need to pull?**

This pulls the Group "Sports" Only....

```bsh
#!/bin/sh    
while read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
awk '/group-title="Sports"/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]}; NR in nr'
sed -i '1i #EXTM3U' emby_iptv_tmp.m3u
done < iptv_download.m3u
mv emby_iptv_tmp.m3u emby_sports.m3u
rm iptv_download.m3u
```

Here's an example of the output desired for all the lines that contain "Sports". I would like this to output all the groups, "General Streams", "Kids", "News" in one run.

Do I just repeat the `awk` statement and output over and over again as I have done with multiple scripts or is there some awk formatting that will do this on a one liner?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="AU: Fox NRL League HD" tvg-logo="" group-title="Sports",AU: Fox NRL League HD
http://**************@gmail.com/**************/53441.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="Golf Channel CA" tvg-name="CA: Golf Channel UHD" tvg-logo="" group-title="Sports",CA: Golf Channel UHD
http://**************@gmail.com/**************/45062.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="Golf Channel CA" tvg-name="CA: Golf Channel" tvg-logo="" group-title="Sports",CA: Golf Channel
http://**************@gmail.com/**************/45369.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="HPItv" tvg-name="CA: HPItv (HORSE RACING)" tvg-logo="" group-title="Sports",CA: HPItv (HORSE RACING)
http://**************@gmail.com/**************/55732.m3u8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know `awk` well enough, I’d just use `grep` and loop over the group names as follows:

```bsh
for i in Sports News" Movies "General Streams"
do
  <input.m3u grep --no-group-separator -A1 'group-title="'"$i"\" >"$i.m3u"
  sed -i '1i #EXTM3U' "$i.m3u"
done
```

This saves the output in files called simply by the group name, e.g. `Sports.m3u` and `General Streams.m3u`.

The [GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) equivalent to this loop is:

```bsh
parallel '<input.m3u grep -A1 group-title=\"{}\" >{}.m3u;sed -i "1i #EXTM3U" {}.m3u' ::: Sports News Movies "General Streams"
```

Comment: @EODCraftStaff please edit and add this to your question!

Comment: Ok it's randomly placing `--` these in the m3u and it crashes the VLC player...any ideas? There on a line all by thereselves. I'll try parallel....

Comment: Ok, that's called a group separator and this works in the command.... `--no-group-separator`

Comment: LOL I actually have a group called 24/7. :) Separate Script.